# Discrete random number generator in Excel

Tags: excel

This post is aimed to show how to write a function to generate random numbers based on discrete distribution in a spreadsheet without calling 
Data-Data Analysis-Random number generation - Discrete distribution.

Comment: SO is a Q&A site, it's not a place to showcase everything you've developed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the solution based on RAND function in Excel for this type of distribution and therefore the next Function should solve this issue.

```
Public Function Discrete(value As Variant, prob As Variant)
Dim i As Integer
Dim cumProb As Single
Dim uniform As Single
Randomize
Application.Volatile
uniform = Rnd
cumProb = prob(1)
i = 1
Do Until cumProb > uniform
i = i + 1
cumProb = cumProb + prob(i)
Loop
Discrete = value(i)
End Function
```

Now you can use function "Discrete" to generate as much values as you need and refresh them by F9

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use MINIFS function as a simple solution!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNxLm.png

Comment: Please, add the code as plain text in your answer.

Comment: Dear
I tried to attach the print screen of the excel sheet but it was changed to a link! If you click the link you can see the procedure.

Comment: Please, read the [Editing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Start your line of code with 4 spaces.